# Definition of target in Linux kernel's Makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kbuild

I'm about to build linux kernel. Before moving to the build step, I have to configure the linux kernel with the command as below

```bash
make menuconfig
```

I can not find any definition of `menuconfig` in [`./Makefile`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Makefile). I also grep-ed in the repo to look for the definition of the target and found nothing. So how does `make` runs some targets relating to **Configuring the kernel** like `menuconfig`, `oldconfig`, etc.

Comment: The `Makefile` you link to has *lots* of `include ...` statements.  The `menuconfig` target could be specified in any of those (or, indeed, anywhere in the `include` hierarchy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel build system makes heavy use of GNU Make features. In the top-level Makefile, the rule for the `menuconfig` target is this one:

```make
%config: outputmakefile scripts_basic FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=scripts/kconfig $@
```

That runs a sub-make for the target in "scripts/kconfig/Makefile". In "scripts/kconfig/Makefile", the rule for the `menuconfig` target is slightly obscured:

```make
define config_rule
PHONY += $(1)
$(1): $(obj)/$($(1)-prog)
    $(Q)$$< $(silent) $(Kconfig)

PHONY += build_$(1)
build_$(1): $(obj)/$($(1)-prog)
endef

$(foreach c, config menuconfig nconfig gconfig xconfig, $(eval $(call config_rule,$(c))))
```